# Find out average loan taken by age group in specific ranges and display them in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Consider the following 2 tables:

```
customer( **c_id**, c_name, c_dob)
customer_loan_taken( **loan_no**, c_id, taken_date, loan_amount)
```

How to find out average loan taken by age group 20-25, 30-35, 40-45, and display them in a single table ?

The table contents are as follows:

### customer table

```
  C_ID C_NAME                         C_DOB
```

---

```
     1 Jainam Jhaveri                 17-FEB-93
     2 Harsh Mehra                    10-DEC-91
     3 Mohit Desai                    15-OCT-75
     4 Raj Gupta                      31-AUG-80
     5 Yash Shah                      24-NOV-85
     6 Dishank Parikh                 02-OCT-78
     7 Chandni Jain                   06-MAR-83
     8 Bhavesh Prajapati              13-MAY-71
     9 Priyank Khandelwal             18-JUN-86
    10 Mihir Vora                     11-NOV-95
```

### customer_loan_taken table

`LOAN_NO       C_ID TAKEN_DAT LOAN_AMOUNT`

---

```
  1011          1 12-SEP-11      100000
  1012          3 20-APR-10      200010
  1013          4 15-OCT-12      150000
  1014          5 04-JAN-13     2500005
  1015          7 15-AUG-16     2600001
  1016          8 21-DEC-16     3500000
  1017          9 13-NOV-17     4000000
  1018         10 05-MAR-18     1010100
```

Comment: Try running my query given below and let me know if you don't get desired output. If it works, please accept the answer by clicking on 'tick' on the right side of the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working in Oracle 12c. The trick to figure out the age can differ on database as datediff is not working in oracle. So modify it accordingly

```
      with customer( c_id, c_name, c_dob) as
      (select 1,'A','31/01/1990' from dual union
      select 2,'A','31/01/1980' from dual union
      select 3,'C','31/01/1970' from dual union
      select 4,'D','31/08/1990' from dual),
      ag as
      (select c.* , 
      FLOOR(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,  to_date(c_dob,'DD/MM/YYYY'))) /12) as age,
      case when FLOOR(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,  to_date(c_dob,'DD/MM/YYYY'))) /12) between 20 and 25 then '20-25' when
      FLOOR(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,  to_date(c_dob,'DD/MM/YYYY'))) /12) between 30 and 35 then '30-35' when
      FLOOR(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,  to_date(c_dob,'DD/MM/YYYY'))) /12) between 40 and 45 then '40-45'
      end as agegroup from customer c
      ),
      customer_loan_taken( loan_no, c_id, taken_date, loan_amount) 
      as
      (
      select 101,1,'01/01/1990',1000 from dual union
      select 102,2,'01/01/1990',2000 from dual union
      select 103,3,'01/01/1990',3000 from dual union
      select 104,4,'01/01/1990',4000 from dual 
      )
      select distinct(ag.agegroup),avg(loan_amount) from customer_loan_taken cl,ag
      where ag.c_id=cl.c_id
      group by ag.agegroup
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  CASE
                WHEN DATEDIFF ("YY", c_dob, GETDATE()) > 20 
                     AND DATEDIFF ("YY", c_dob, GETDATE()) <= 25 THEN '20-25'
                WHEN DATEDIFF ("YY", c_dob, GETDATE()) > 25 
                     AND DATEDIFF ("YY", c_dob, GETDATE()) <= 30 THEN '25-30'
                WHEN DATEDIFF ("YY", c_dob, GETDATE()) > 30 
                     AND DATEDIFF ("YY", c_dob, GETDATE()) <= 35 THEN '30-35'
                END AS rangedate,
                l.loan_amount
    FROM    customer
            INNER JOIN customer_loan_taken l ON customer.c_id = l.c_id
)

SELECT   rangedate, 
         AVG(loan_amount) average 
FROM     cte
GROUP BY rangedate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select avg(loan_amt) "LOAN_AVG",age_range from(
  select l.loan_amount as loan_amt,
  (case
  when FLOOR((months_between(sysdate,to_CHAR(c.c_dob,'DD-MON-YYYY')))/12) 
  between 20 and 25 then '20-25'
  when FLOOR((months_between(sysdate,to_CHAR(c.c_dob,'DD-MON-YYYY')))/12) 
  between 30 and 35 then '30-35'
  when FLOOR((months_between(sysdate,to_CHAR(c.c_dob,'DD-MON-YYYY')))/12) 
  between 40 and 45 then '40-45'
  else '46-90'
  end) as age_range
from customer c,cust_loan_taken l
 where c.C_ID=l.C_ID) a
 group by age_range;
```